# My Camera preview it was showing wrong display and i need to stored this snap into SD card HOW?

Tags: android, android-layout, coding-style, android-manifest

This camera program showing horizontal preview while we are watching vertically like its was showing 90'angle and also it was not storing into my SD card ..any body help me how to change my surface angle and how it will be changed into SD card ??

1.my preview class:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "Preview";
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    public Camera camera;
     Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);


            camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                    try {
                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));  
                        outStream.write(data);
                        outStream.close();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                    }
                        Preview.this.invalidate();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera = null;
    }
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.draw(canvas);
            Paint p= new Paint(Color.RED);
            Log.d(TAG,"draw");
            canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, p );
    }
}
```

2.MYCameraDemo class

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
public class CameraDemo extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
    Camera camera;
    Preview preview;
    Button buttonClick;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        preview = new Preview(this);
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

        buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
        buttonClick.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
    }
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for raw picture */
    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                        outStream = CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()), 0); 

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));  
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: At finally....what's you do.....I also face out same problem.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this link can help you.

http://adblogcat.com/a-camera-preview-with-a-bounding-box-like-google-goggles/

Here is the onSurfaceChange method which sets the right orientation

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    //Log.i(TAG, "Preview: surfaceChanged() - size now " + w + "x" + h);
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    try {
        mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        mParameters.set("orientation","landscape");
        for (Integer i : mParameters.getSupportedPreviewFormats()) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "supported preview format: " + i);
        }

        List<Size> sizes = mParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "supported preview size: " + size.width + "x" + size.height);
        }
        mCamera.setParameters(mParameters); // apply the changes
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // older phone - doesn't support these calls
    }

    //updateBufferSize(); // then use them to calculate

    Size p = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    //Log.i(TAG, "Preview: checking it was set: " + p.width + "x" + p.height); // DEBUG
    mCamera.startPreview();
}

public Parameters getCameraParameters(){
    return mCamera.getParameters();
}
```

The article sets the parameters to landscape. I see you do not have this in your code.

Also, for saving images I see two methods:

```
private boolean savePhoto(Bitmap bm) {
FileOutputStream image = null;
try {
    image = new FileOutputStream(mLocation);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, image);
if (bm != null) {
    int h = bm.getHeight();
    int w = bm.getWidth();
    //Log.i(TAG, "savePhoto(): Bitmap WxH is " + w + "x" + h);
} else {
    //Log.i(TAG, "savePhoto(): Bitmap is null..");
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}

and

```
public Bitmap getPic(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
System.gc();
Bitmap b = null;
Size s = mParameters.getPreviewSize();

YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(mBuffer, ImageFormat.NV21, s.width, s.height, null);
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(x, y, width, height), 100, outStream); // make JPG
b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outStream.toByteArray(), 0, outStream.size());
if (b != null) {
    //Log.i(TAG, "getPic() WxH:" + b.getWidth() + "x" + b.getHeight());
} else {
    //Log.i(TAG, "getPic(): Bitmap is null..");
}
yuvimage = null;
outStream = null;
System.gc();
return b;
```

}

And you need to use android 2.2